# File name differs from already included file name only in casing. Material UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have created a new Typescript React application and have added the Material UI packages. However, when I come to import I get the following type of error in VS Code - although the applciation still builds and runs.

> File name
> 'd:/GitLocal/myApp/node_modules/@mui/material/IconButton/index.d.ts'
> differs from already included file name
> 'D:/GitLocal/myApp/node_modules/@mui/material/IconButton/index.d.ts'
> only in casing.

the only difference is the drive letter where one is **d** and the other is capitol **D**. I could just try to ignore it or even use:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false
  }
```

However this is not a good solution. I was wondering if anyone else has had this issue and how did they get shot of it?

Answer (score 3):

I simply ran `npm update` and that seemed to resolve the issue. Was gonna delete this question but figured someone may find it handy one day!?

Comment: I did this (ran `npm update`) and reloaded the VSCode window, because even after running the command the error continued to appear, and the error disappeared. So, thank you.